# Will my taxes be increased after receiving green card?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, permanent-resident, university

Today, I am informed that my green card application is approved and I will receive my physical green card in the next week or so. I work as a graduate research assistant in a University at South Carolina. Before receiving my green card, I was on F-1 student visa. Will my taxes be increased after receiving green card?

Comment: It will depend on your university's rules, but you may be required to pay FICA (social security tax) during the summer and other breaks between semesters.  You were previously exempt from FICA entirely because of your nonresident status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will my taxes be increased after receiving green card?

Typically, no. However, there'll be a few changes in your tax forms, e.g. nonresident aliens are exempt from FBAR while [resident aliens](https://international.umw.edu/international-services/resources-for-living-in-the-u-s/immigration-and-tax-law-definitions/resident-of-nonresident-for-tax-purposes/) are not, nonresident aliens file Form 1040NR whereas resident aliens file Form 1040, and I believe [some tax treaty clauses only apply to nonresident aliens](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/taxation-of-nonresident-aliens-1)  (->  that's the only change I can think of that could lead to a slight increase in your taxes).

---

To connect your immigration status (F1 vs. green card) with the IRS terminology (resident aliens vs. nonresident aliens):

- F and J student visa holders are considered non-resident aliens during their first five calendar years in the U.S.
- Having a green card makes you a resident alien.

---

FYI [What shall one do after receiving a green card?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12414/164)

Comment: 1099 should be 1040, I believe?

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset thanks, yes, fixed!